# How to Insert Hindi Text into SQLite DataBase C# windows 8.1 phone development?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

How to Insert Hindi Text into SQLite DataBase C# windows 8.1 phone development as I am getting Question marks like this ???? ???  instead of Hindi Text .
please someone help me to resolve this problem.

I have to insert the Hindi Text using below Hindi text unicode to sqlite db :

```
\u0926\u093f\u0932\u0936\u093e\u0926 \u0917\u093e\u0930\u094d\u0921\u0928
```

[image]

Comment: May be nvarchar data type for that column will help you on that.

Comment: @Janak That's not how SQLite works.

Comment: How exactly did you insert the data? By hand, or with a C# program?

Comment: Is this related to your editor? If data stored properly but editor shows badly, this could be your editor display issue